# Handling new user requests from a Swift client

Tags: php, sql, api

I am starting to play with POST request to save in my server the user token so I can send push notifications in Swift ([this is the Swift code)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/86611/save-token-id-into-a-database-in-swift). This is the PHP file that processes the request (please note that I will improve it using prepare statements to prevent SQL injection):

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set("display_errors", 1);
// typically there would be much more
// validation done on the request and
// cleaner database handling

// create link to database
$host = "localhost";
$db = "myDatabase";
$dbuser = "admin";
$dbpass = "mypassword";

$now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$dbConnection = mysql_connect($host, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if ($dbConnection) {
    mysql_select_db($db, $dbConnection);
} else {
    // return error status code
    sendAPIResponse(500);
    return;
}



// get the post body
$userid = $_REQUEST['user'];
$token = $_REQUEST['token'];


if (empty($userid) || empty($token)) {
    sendAPIResponse(400);
    return;
}

// determine if user exists
$sql = "SELECT user_id 
        FROM users 
        WHERE user_id='".$userid."' LIMIT 1;";
$query = mysql_query($sql, $dbConnection);
$userExists = mysql_fetch_row($query);

// add a 'user' record
if (!$userExists) {

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_id) 
            VALUES ('".$userid."');";
    if (!mysql_query($sql, $dbConnection)) {
        // return error
        sendAPIResponse(400);
        return;
    }

}

// determine if token already exists
$sql = "SELECT token 
        FROM user_tokens 
        WHERE user_id='".$userid."' 
          AND token='".$token."' LIMIT 1;";
$query = mysql_query($sql, $dbConnection);
$tokenExists = mysql_fetch_row($query);

// add a token for current user
if (!$tokenExists) {

    $sql = "INSERT INTO user_tokens (user_id, token, datecreated) 
            VALUES ('".$userid."','".$token."','".$now."');";
    if (!mysql_query($sql, $dbConnection)) {
        // return error
        sendAPIResponse(400);
        return;
    }
}

// close the database connection
mysql_close($dbConnection);

// return success
sendAPIResponse(200);



date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

function getStatusCodeMessage($status) {

    $codes = Array(
        100 => 'Continue',
        101 => 'Switching Protocols',
        200 => 'OK',
        201 => 'Created',
        202 => 'Accepted',
        203 => 'Non-Authoritative Information',
        204 => 'No Content',
        205 => 'Reset Content',
        206 => 'Partial Content',
        300 => 'Multiple Choices',
        301 => 'Moved Permanently',
        302 => 'Found',
        303 => 'See Other',
        304 => 'Not Modified',
        305 => 'Use Proxy',
        306 => '(Unused)',
        307 => 'Temporary Redirect',
        400 => 'Bad Request',
        401 => 'Unauthorized',
        402 => 'Payment Required',
        403 => 'Forbidden',
        404 => 'Not Found',
        405 => 'Method Not Allowed',
        406 => 'Not Acceptable',
        407 => 'Proxy Authentication Required',
        408 => 'Request Timeout',
        409 => 'Conflict',
        410 => 'Gone',
        411 => 'Length Required',
        412 => 'Precondition Failed',
        413 => 'Request Entity Too Large',
        414 => 'Request-URI Too Long',
        415 => 'Unsupported Media Type',
        416 => 'Requested Range Not Satisfiable',
        417 => 'Expectation Failed',
        500 => 'Internal Server Error',
        501 => 'Not Implemented',
        502 => 'Bad Gateway',
        503 => 'Service Unavailable',
        504 => 'Gateway Timeout',
        505 => 'HTTP Version Not Supported'
    );

    return (isset($codes[$status])) ? $codes[$status] : '';
}

// Helper method to send a HTTP response code/message
function sendAPIResponse($status = 200, $body = '', $content_type = 'text/html') {

    $status_header = 'HTTP/1.1 ' . $status . ' ' . getStatusCodeMessage($status);
    header($status_header);
    header('Content-type: ' . $content_type);


}

?>
```

If somebody gets the correct address:

> http://www.myServer.com/api/v1.0/saveToken.php

would he be capable of sending a post request adding fake users and token IDs?

Shall I use an API key (not sure is the correct word) to "identify" the user?

```
$apiKey = $_REQUEST['apiKey'];
if(isset($apiKey)){

  if($apiKey == 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'){

  //then run the code

 }
```

Comment: Please look into SQL injection and how to defend against them (prepared statements). Currently, your code is extremely vulnerable. And don't use `mysql_` as it's deprecated for quite a while, use `mysqli_` or `pdo` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If somebody gets the correct address `http://www.myServer.com/api/v1.0/saveToken.php`, would he be capable to send a post request adding fake users and token ids?

Sure, why wouldn't an attacker be able to do that?

You can test this yourself, either by writing a short script, or using a plugin such as tamper data for firefox. Or, as you are using `REQUEST` instead of `POST`, just pass the values as `GET`.

So if you want to avoid this, you need some kind of authentication mechanism (and you obviously need to fix the SQL injection).

Other than the use of `mysql_` which is deprecated for a long time, and the SQL injection, your PHP code looks good. I would probably move some of the code to it's own function (such as `addUser`, `selectUser`, `addToken`, etc) to make it even easier to read. And instead of setting the header and status message yourself you could use `http_response_code`.