# Save token id into a database in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to save my users tokens id into my database using POST request in Swift (here [PHP code here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/86601/handle-post-request-from-ios-device-swift-in-php)). I am a bit confused about synchronous and asynchronous request.

1. Is this code the right way to do it?
2. would the app crash if there is a connection problem while it is sending the synchronous request
3. shall I use an api key (not sure is the correct word) to "identify" the user

---

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {

    var userId = "001" //I just use it as USER number 1

    // prepare the tolen to be saved from <xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx> to xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    var token = NSString(format: "%@", deviceToken)
    token = token.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(
        "<",
        withString: "")
    token = token.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(
        ">",
        withString: "")
    token = token.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in


        var postBody = NSString(format: "user=%@&token=%@", userId, token)
        var endBody = NSURL(string: "http://www.myServer.com/api/v1.0/saveToken.php")
        var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: endBody!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 30.0)

        request.HTTPMethod = "POST";
        request.HTTPBody = postBody.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")


        var response: NSURLResponse?
        var error: NSError?

        NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error: &error)

        println(response)
        println(error)

    })

    }
```

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This:

```
var token = NSString(format: "%@", deviceToken)
token = token.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("<", withString: "")
token = token.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(">", withString: "")
token = token.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
```

is actually a bad method to convert an `NSData` object to an `NSString`
(containing the bytes in hexadecimal). It relies on `description`
having the format

```
<01020304 05060708 090a0b0c 0d0e0f10>
```

which is not officially documented. In most cases, the `description` of
an object is only suitable for debugging purposes, but not for further
processing.

I would convert all data bytes explicitly to create the string. Here is a possible implementation as an `NSData` extension method:

```
extension NSData {
    func hexString() -> String {
        // "Array" of all bytes:
        let bytes = UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>(start: UnsafePointer(self.bytes), count:self.length)
        // Array of hex strings, one for each byte:
        let hexBytes = map(bytes) { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }
        // Concatenate all hex strings:
        return "".join(hexBytes)
    }
}
```

which can be used as

```
let token = deviceToken.hexString()
```

---

With

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { ... }
```

you dispatch the URL request to the *main queue* where it blocks the
UI. You can use `dispatch_get_global_queue()` instead to dispatch
it to a background thread, or simply use `sendAsynchronousRequest()`:

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {
    (response, data, error) -> Void in

    if data != nil {
        println("data: \(data)")
    } else {
        println("failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Now the request is done in the background and then the completion
handler called on the main thread.

In the case of an connection problem, the completion handler is called
with `data == nil` and `error != nil` containing information about the
problem.

---

> shall I use an api key (not sure is the correct word) to "identify" the user

This question is a bit broad and depends on what you are trying to 
achieve. Here are some comparisons of the available methods:

- [CFUUID Vs. advertisingIdentifier Vs. identifierForVendor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18312035/cfuuid-vs-advertisingidentifier-vs-identifierforvendor)
- [The Developer’s Guide to Unique Identifiers](http://possiblemobile.com/2013/04/unique-identifiers/)

which might serve as a starting point for your further research.

Comment: Although, is `data` guaranteed to be `nil`?  I thought it was generally better to check `if error != nil`.

Comment: @nhgrif: No, it is the other way around (see for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/29384651/1187415). – But here is does not matter, the sendAsynchronousRequest() documentation is quite clear that either data != nil and error == nil or vice versa.

Comment: @MartinR can you please check if my modified code looks ok now? thanks

Comment: @mattia: You should not edit your question after receiving answers. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*: *"... should not append your revised code to the question"*. You can post a new question instead.

Answer (score 5):

The extension on NSData by @martin-r can be rewritten in Swift 2 as a computed property using map reduce as follows:

```
extension NSData {
    var hexString: String {
        let bytes = UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>(start: UnsafePointer(self.bytes), count:self.length)
        return bytes.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.reduce("", combine: { $0 + $1 })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This works in Swift 3:

```
let tokenString = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})
```